# printf %s inteira em C

Tags: c, string

Eu estou tentando fazer aparecer na tela todos os caracteres da string tipoPersonagem[0], porém só está saindo a última letra da string, alguém me ajuda no que estou errando?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

char tipoPersonagem[3][100] = {{'Lutador'}, {'Ninja'}, {'Apelão'}};

int main()
{
    //Definição para acentos e cedilha
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf("%s.", tipoPersonagem[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **strings** em C são definidas com **"**(aspas duplas), enquanto **'**(aspas simples) são utilizadas para representar apenas **um caractere**. Logo, o código fica:

```
char tipoPersonagem[3][100] = {{"Lutador"}, {"Ninja"}, {"Apelão"}};
```

Comment: era só isso? nossa men valeu kkkkk sempre usei ' ' ou " " quando parecia visualmente mais bonito, não sabia que tinha diferença.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueRodriguesGrund somente isso! Não esquece de marcar a resposta como correta! Boa noite!